# Executing perl script in linux gives :Exec format error. Wrong Architecture

Tags: linux, perl

i have perl script that used to be working great , once i edit it in windows 
and convert it to UTF-8 and then via FTP return it .
also did:

```
chmod +x foo.pl
```

and then when i try to run it :

```
 ./foo.pl
im getting this error:
./foo.pl: Exec format error. Wrong Architecture.
```

what ? what wrong Architecture ? whats going on here ?

Comment: What does the first line of the script look like?

Comment: Looks like you use binaries that are not compiled for your OS.

Comment: no binaries at all.. this script just doing string manipulation on files
its 200 lines script

Comment: 64bit Perl on a 32bit OS?

Comment: Did you ever run the file on windows? If so you probably changed the first line to point to a different path for where perl is installed. That could be causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to the Windows-style line endings. To solve, on the unix prompt: vi foo.pl and then :set ff=unix followed by :wq to save and quit.